# I am creating a program to make a randomly generated land using a JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

I am trying to paint trees onto the land and need to know if you can create an object or something where you can call tree with some coordinates and it will then create a tree there. By painting it down on a 2d JFrame.

Comment: Sorry. But I cannot understand your question. Can you re-phrase it sharing more details of what you want ??

Comment: You don't paint on a JFrame, you paint on a Graphics (or Graphics2D)

Answer (score 0):

You don't paint on a JFrame, you paint on a Graphics (or Graphics2D). A JFrame (or any Component) must be able to paint it's content at any time. This means that your JFrame would have to keep a copy of the whole scene in one form or an other (either a collection of drawable objects, or a bitmap image on which the objects would be drawn only once).

As for the drawable objects, you just need a method that knows how to paint itself:

```
void paint(Graphics g, int x, int y);
```

or

```
void paint(Graphics2D g, double x, double y);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I phrased the question wrong. I am using a paint component and I was just wondering if there was a way that I could create a paint object where I can call it with coordinates and it would paint itself there on the paint component.

Comment: @TrevorFitzgerald are your looking for class that paints trees?